# I've found this definition somewhere, but I can't find its formal name. Can someone help me? $P_{A}(x)=\left\{a \in A: d(a, x)=r_{A}(x)\right\}$

Tags: analysis, metric-spaces

$P_{A}(x)=\left\{a \in A: d(a, x)=r_{A}(x)\right\}$
Where
$r_{A}(x)=\inf _{a \in A} d(a, x)$

Comment: Is $d$ a distance or some metric?

Comment: Subset of "proximity points" (translating directly, probably not what it's called in English) of $x$ in $A$ (w.r.t metric $d$) or some such. The subset can also be empty.

Comment: One has $x$ and $A$ are an element and a subset of some metric space $E$ respectively and $P_A$ goes from $E$ to the set of subsets of $A$. Note $\Gamma$ the frontier of the ball centered in $x$ and radius $r_x$ where $r_x=$ distance of $x$ to $A$. The interior of $A$ is clearly disjoint of $\Gamma$.

 $P_A(x)$ is the intersection of $\Gamma$ with the frontier of $A$. I don't know is this function has a formal name.